# Do BitCoin wallets generated by websites have validity?

Tags: wallet

Is there a way to generate my own Bitcoin address offline without using the websites?

Answer (score 2):

You can save the [bitaddress.org](https://www.bitaddress.org) site and load it offline and it will still work.

You can also use [VanityGen](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Vanitygen) to generate "vanity" addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use just about any bitcoin client to do this - bitcoin-qt, electrum, multibit, armory etc. They can all generate private keys and addresses offline.